# Facebook likes (with comments) not working well on a password/login protected website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, passwords, facebook-like

I am working with our web developer to integrate Facebook Likes (with comments) onto our website. However, he is having problems because FB doesn't work very well with sites where a log in is required. Currently when you click on the 'like' button the 'like' turns into 'confirm'. You then have to click on 'confirm' and another box appears showing how the like will appear on your FB page saying 'Click Like to post this to your profile' with the option of 'like' or cancel. If you click on 'like' then it allows the comment box to pop up then you can add a comment and post to FB.

There are currently too many clicks for this to work. Does anyone have any advice? Would it be better to just use straight likes with the number perhaps or is this a common problem with website that require a login. We just want users to be able to click once, add their comment and post it to FB.

Any help would be really apprecaited. If it is technical that is fine as I will pass replies onto my developer.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will generally happen for URLs and sites that are new to the Facebook scraper. It is a security measure to prevent like-jacking that some sites have done in the past. You should ensure that you test your site fully with the [Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and after some confirmed 'likes', that step will be automatically removed and future users will just have to click like once.

Where you are gating content behind a login, I would additionally recommend that you show different HTML (including OG tags) for anything detected with the Facebook scraper User Agent (see [*When does Facebook scrape my page?*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#faq) on the [Like Button FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#faq)) so that, for example, the OG tags for a product detail page are picked up correctly even though the scraper is technically not logged in.